# Modify AdditionalLibraryDirectories in vcxproj after import

Tags: c++, msbuild

I have C++ project that references a nuget package. Inside this vcxproj I have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="16.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="..\packages\mypackage.props" Condition="Exists("..\packages\mypackage.props")" />
  ...
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='SpecialConfig|x64'">
    <Link>
      <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
 
  <Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\mypackage.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\mypackage.props'))" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Inside mypackage.props

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(PlatformToolset)' == 'v142' And '$(Platform)' == 'x64'">
    <Link>
      <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\..\lib\$(Configuration);%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
</Project>
```

$Configuration may be only debug or release and it is set by the nuget package author.
In my vcxproj I have more than just debug and release configurations. Is there a way to override configuration temporarily before import? Or modify AdditionalLibraryDirectories after Import?

Comment: "modify AdditionalLibraryDirectories after import" - yes. "override configuration temporarily before import" - probably yes. Also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/property-functions?view=vs-2022

Comment: You can save the current `Configuration` value to another property, `Import`, and then restore the `Configuration` value that you saved. I can provide an example.

Comment: The NuGet package author should NOT be changing the `Configuration` property. Report a defect against the package if possible.

Comment: То @Jonathan Dodds  I actually tried this and it seems not possible. The Import is executed and not evaluated so it stays in memory with "$(Configuration)" usage.

Comment: Are you saying that the property reference `$(Configuration)` is not replaced with the property value? Can you share more of the code from `mypackage.props`? Can you show the parent of the `Link` element and the closing tags for the `Link` and `AdditionalLibraryDirectories` elements?

Comment: It is replaced with "SpecialConfig" eventually. But it is not what I want. I want to be able to put "Release" instead